# Everytime goto Activity increase instance counts in AndroidDevMetrics in android

Tags: java, android, performance, metrics, multiple-instances

I have added [AndroidDevMetrics](https://github.com/frogermcs/AndroidDevMetrics) library in my project which has many activities and screens.

My app working fine and no lags also no frame drops u can see from image i will add below.

The problem is that; the instance count for each activity got increased as i go to that activity again and again. You can have better view from image attached below. I went to ArtistDetailsActivity 5 times from HomeActivity. and only 1 times for some other screens.

[image: Current status of my app through AndroidDevMetrics]

I Als have tried some ways to remove old instances of activities. Not worked.

Niether the number of instances are restrained to 1, Nor the app is creating any problem with that.

My Questions are:

1. Is this normal behaviour? (About multiple instance of activity as we render it again).
2. If not normal behaviour. How can i remove old instances of activity.
3. Will it create any impact on my app on heavy usage or low end devices

Thanks for reading uptill here.

I appreciate any help or direction in this regards. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain a single instance of the same activity then you could use this

```
Intent nextScreen = new Intent(currentActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
nextScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(nextScreen);
```

And if you want all the activities from stack being cleared

```
finishAffinity();
```

For more information

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: Thanks @Lakhwinder for reply. I have apply this.
This actually removes my old activities from stack.
And when i press back button to go to back activity. It kills the app.
I don't need that. 
Also i have asked 3 questions. Can you please answer them also. Its more of a conceptual question.

Comment: Did you try,  CLEAR TOP FLAG